# Is it possible to have more than one var in a do-while cycle?

Tags: javascript, do-while

Is it possible something like this or should I split my cycle into two distinct `do-while` cycles?
Because it doesn't work, it only appears once and stops, when my mission is to continually ask the number and odd or even to the user until he gives them to me. My question was about the possibility to execute two different `var` in one single do in a `do-while` cycle

```
//Data
var userWord;
var userNumber;

// The user choose between odd or even a number between 1 and 5.
do {
    userWord = prompt("Choose odd or even");
    userNumber = parseInt(prompt("Give me a number between 1 and 5"));
} while (userWord.length == 0 && userNumber == 0);
```

The condition in the `while` in my mind is "if the value you put is 0, so nothing, then the question is asked again until you write somenthing.

Comment: Use `||` if you want to repeat when either of the conditions is true.

Comment: What if they type 6?

Comment: "is it possible?" Yes. What happens when you run this code? And what do you want it to do differently.

Comment: The condition can be anything you want, so it can contain as many variables as you want to test.

Comment: @Bamar I should put a >5 condition

Comment: Why asking the user to enter the first number again when they enter an invalid second number?

Comment: You need to learn the difference between `&&` and `||`. How can a number be 0 and also >5 at the same time?

Comment: @Barmar right so `while (userWord.length == 0 && userNumber == 0 || userNumber > 5);` now it's an or and not an and, so just one of the true must be true

Comment: @AlonEitan they must enter only one number, do I've written it in a bad way so two number are asked?

Comment: Your code will ask them to enter another number if they don't fill in even/odd. Or will ask them for even/odd again if they entered an incorrect number.

Comment: @Barmar It's true, I've checked now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `||`, not `&&`. This is true when any of the sub-conditions are true. Your condition will only be true when *all* of the sub-conditions are true.

```js
var userWord;
var userNumber;

// The user choose between odd or even a number between 1 and 5.
do {
  userWord = prompt("Choose odd or even");
  userNumber = parseInt(prompt("Give me a number between 1 and 5"));
} while (userWord.length == 0 || userNumber < 1 || userNumber > 5);
console.log(userWord, userNumber);
```

It would be nicer for the user if you had separate loops for each input, so they don't have to re-enter both when they get one of them wrong.

```js
var userWord;
var userNumber;

do {
  userWord = prompt("Choose odd or even");
} while (userWord.length == 0);

do {
  userNumber = parseInt(prompt("Give me a number between 1 and 5"));
} while (userNumber < 1 || userNumber > 5)

console.log(userWord, userNumber);
```

Comment: Works completely fine! If I write for example 6 the code asks again odd or even, this is because they are in the same do-while and if the cycle starts again then everything is asked again right?

Comment: Yes, I just added how to split them up.

Comment: Amazing, you answered my question thanks!